# Blender python iteration of importing model gets slower

Tags: python, memory-management

I'm doing a project with python in blender and let me summarize its process.

1. Import a .pmx file(kind of 3d model)

   ```
       start = time.time()
       bpy.ops.mmd_tools.import_model(
           filepath=str(model_path), 
           files=[{
               "name":os.path.basename(model_path), 
               "name":os.path.basename(model_path)
           }], 
           directory=os.path.dirname(model_path), 
           types={'MESH', 'ARMATURE', 'MORPHS'}, 
           scale=0.08, 
           log_level='WARNING')
       #This import_model function is from addon.
       print("import time :", time.time() - start)
   ```
2. Analyze and append some data to a global variable '`list[]`'
3. Delete every data(Object, Meshes, Materials, Textures, images, texts and collections), and even `Purge_all`.

   ```
   def clean_blender():

   for dataset in [bpy.data.objects, bpy.data.meshes,
                   bpy.data.materials, bpy.data.textures, bpy.data.images, bpy.data.texts,
                   bpy.data.collections]:
       for key, value in dataset.items():
           if key != 'camera' and key != 'light' and value.name != 'Text':
               dataset.remove(value, do_unlink = True)
   ```

   This `clean_blender()` deletes every data from my scene, and `purge_all()` delete all orphan datas.

   ```
   def purge_all():
       area = bpy.context.area
       old_type = area.type
       area.type = 'OUTLINER'
       bpy.context.space_data.display_mode = 'ORPHAN_DATA'
       bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge()
       area.type = old_type
   ```

   4. Iterate 1 ~ 3 for every 3d models.

But I figured out that each time for "importing" model gets longer, and I checked it via `time.time()` by iterating just only one file in `While 1:`. And the time spent on importing(1 Loop) got longer overtime. I've tried many other options

1. No 'For loop', iterate manually like `import(file_list[0])` `import(file_list[0])` `import(file_list[0])`...
2. `import gc` and `gc.collect()`
3. modify api and make `dummy_view_layer_update()` to run `view_layer_update()` only at the end of my script

However It was all same. But the weird thing is that after I exit my script and get back to blender, everything is deleted successfully. And when re - run script, then the speed gets back as fast as the first time I ran my program and gets slower again.

So my conclusion is that Process 3 - 'Delete every data' works fine after the script exits, but not properly during running(Maybe because blender is blocked while running script?) . It is just a guess, and I can't even figure out what should I do.

Or is it just an innate problem of blender python?

Thanks.

Comment: Could try seeing what's at the top of the profile, [here](https://pastebin.com/WdyYp1nC)'s the boilerplate I use.

Comment: If all else fails, you could also try `read_homefile` to get a new file after each import. You'd probably have to move some of your code to run in a handler that runs after the new file is loaded.

Comment: @scurest Thanks for your idea, but it seems no problem in profiling. And when I `read_homefile`, it resets everything including my script, and it stops. Because I have to iterate about 5000 files, I think it isn't a proper solution.

Comment: You can try using `batch_remove` if you have a lot of objects, might speed things a bit. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.batch_remove It take a list of IDs as input Also you might want to explore [application timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html) to delay the execution of next loop for a bit, maybe there is a thread that never has time to finish when deleting things. idk :)